# How to use the sklearn.cluster.MeanShift algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I have a problem where I need to predict a list of objects based on previous history of the usage of the objects. It is a recommendation system in short.

I figured I can use clustering on existing data, and then try to find pattern among the clusters.

For this I came acros scikit-learn library in python, and i think it will work.

But I need to know how I will use one of their clustering algorithms(say MeanShift) , since the examples they provide mostly work on their own datasets provided in the library itself.

So,

1. How do I organize my data so that I can use the MeanShift class from sklearn.cluster package?
2. My data points are multidimensional, so will I be able to use sklearn package in the first place? they haven't mentioned any constraints.
3. If I can cluster multidimensional data points, will I have to do dimensionality reduction? ( I don't know how to do this either, but I am aware of the concept)

I have done some data mining in one of my courses, but these are new waters for me, any help in terms of pointing to resources/tutorials will be appreciated hightly.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to implement a recommendation system, maybe look into collaborative filtering, not clustering.

Comment: @AndreasMueller : thank you, I am going to use Collaborative filtering, but since I have a huge data set, I have to use clustering before CF, to reduce the running time....i decided to do this after reading several papers on recommendation systems...